# forEach loop for getting data firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6

I have a code:

```
const { uid } = firebaseConfig.auth().currentUser;
const ref = db.collection('categories').doc(uid);

ref.onSnapshot(
  snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(item => console.log(item.data()));
  },
  err => {
    console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
  }
);
```

and I got error: `Uncaught TypeError: snapshot.forEach is not a function`
Where did I make a mistake?
firebase version: `^6.2.0`

Comment: What is `snapshot`?

Comment: probably snapshot is a record not an array of records

Comment: Where you've defined `snapshot ` variable? What the data inside?

Comment: try to `log` snapshot and check whether it is array or not

Answer (score 0):

Try to `log` snapshot and check whether it is array or not.[You might be looking for this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots)

Answer (score 0):

Since your `ref` points to a specific document, your `onSnapshot` callback will get called with a single [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) which doesn't have a `forEach()`.

If you'd attach to an entire collection or a query, you'd get a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) which *does* have a `forEach` method.

---

If you really want to get a `QuerySnapshot` for a single document of which you know the ID, you can use a query on the document ID:

```
const ref = db.collection('categories').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', uid)
```